Can a weapon slay a person?
Does the subject of the verb "slew/slay" have to be a person? Consider the following sentence I wrote:

Ram then fired an arrow that slew Subahu.

Is the above sentence correct? Here, "an arrow" is the subject of "slew".
Or should I write as follows?

Ram then slew Subahu by firing an arrow at him.


There must be thousands of written instances of slain by a bullet in Google Books. Which is semantically much the same as slain by an arrow. There won't be so many instances of slain by a gun or ...a bow, because they're just the means of delivery - it's the bullet or arrow that does the actal slaying.

The question posed in a more conventional way is: Can a person slay another?

Slay is usually used with a person doing the killing, rather than referring to a weapon or other force. "...an arrow that killed Subahu" would be better.
Merriam-Webster has a usage note that says

SLAY is a chiefly literary term implying deliberateness and violence but not necessarily motive.

A weapon or inanimate object cannot do something deliberately.
It is commonly used in the passive to indicate that someone was killed, without specifying who did the slaying, like "Two people, one a teenager, were slain Tuesday in separate incidents in the District, the police said." (Dictionary.com)
Of Merriam-Webster's examples, those that indicate who or what is doing the slaying all involve people or groups of people:

Among the dozen police officers killed this year, at least eight have been slain by armed groups.


Players work together to strategize and slay the monsters by rolling dice and choosing cards.


Those lyrics allude to the March 2023 mass shooting at the Covenant School, an elementary school in the Green Hills neighborhood of Nashville in which three adults and three children were slain by an assailant.


I have a copy of Gustave Doré's engraving 'The Disobedient Prophet Slain by a Lion'. 'Man Slain by a Tiger' is a print by Clive Hicks-Jenkins. 'After the murder Orestes calls upon. Zeus to avenge the orphaned brood of an eagle slain by an adder.' The Serpent at the Breast William Whallon, 1958. 'Tragically slain by a scorpion but immortalized in legend, Orion now resides among the heavens.'

"Guns don't kill people, I kill people", in the words of Jon Lajoie. But in the passive, slain by a bullet is common enough - by can both identify the agent performing an action and the means of performing it.

I just love answers that just tell it like it is.  Sure, an animal can slay you but it's ain't common. But I draw the line at insect.

@Lambie - "Spenser's poem Muiopotmos, or The Fate of the Butterflie (1591) tells the tale of a butterfly, Clarion, grimly slain by a spider, Aragnoll". [Oxford] Essays in Criticism, Volume 69, Issue 2, April 2019.

@MichaelHarvey Their doing it to each other now, are they? All is possible in love and war.

@Lambie - Yet still Aragnoll (so his foe was hight)
Lay lurking couertly him to surprise,
And all his gins that him entangle might,
Drest in good order as he could deuise.
At length the foolish Flie without foresight,
As he that did all danger quite despise,
Toward those parts came flying careleslie ,
Where hidden was his hatefull enemie.

@MichaelHarvey Well, one can see where poor old Lewis got his prosody. :)

@lambie - it goes on for 441 lines, and has been called 'notoriously enigmatic'.

'Slew' is a synonym for 'killed', and yes, someone can be killed by an arrow. Your first sentence is correct. So is the second. No ancient person ever said 'Arrows don't slay people; people do'.
If someone is killed by an arrow, bullet, hurled rock, etc, the final cause of the death is that object, but the first ('proximate') cause is the person firing or throwing the object.
